# preventDefault() и checkbox

Tags: checkbox

На сайте есть событие

`document.querySelector(".wrapper").onclick = (event)=>{}`

в него добавлено

`event.preventDefault()`

так на сайте есть checkbox.
который находится в form

но с отключенным дефолтным поведением чекбокс не нажимается.
как мне совместить обязательное отсутствие обновления страницы и при необходимости активный
чекбокс для отправки этого на сервер без перезагрузки

Comment: Изменение чекбокса не приводит к обновлению страницы, поэтому никакой preventDefault в принципе не нужен

Comment: На сайте есть тег form. он то и обновляет страницу при нажатии отправить

Comment: Но не при нажатии чекбокса же, в чекбоксе preventDefault не нужен

Comment: но онклик же работает на весь документ. могу ли я как то огородить лишь 1 чекбокс

Comment: А зачем вы добавляете онклик на весь документ?

Comment: что бы удобно было отлавливать взаимодействия с кнопками и прочим контентом

Comment: Так смешивать разные вещи в одну кучу наоборот неудобно, и вот вы сейчас напоролись на одно из таких неудобств

Comment: что бы не вешать на 1 кнопку по эвенту. а уже в (event)=>{} 
 проверять на что было нажато

Comment: как лучше поступить ?

Comment: «проверять на что было нажато» — ну вот значит как вариант проверяйте, нажата ли кнопка отправить, и вызывайте preventDefault только если нажата кнопка отправить и никогда иначе

Comment: я пытался добавить preventDefault  в if но страница всё равно перезагружалась

Comment: Значит неправильно добавляли как-то

Comment: Но вообще «что бы не вешать на 1 кнопку по эвенту» — что вам мешает вешать на 1 кнопку по эвенту? Это же разделение ответственности, повышение контроля над кодом, в общем удобно

Comment: приму к сведенью, спасибо.